# BeautifulSoup4 returns the wrong HTML?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to use Beautifulsoup to web-scrape job posts on Indeed.com. However, when I scrape an URL, the HTML that is returned is not the same as the HTML as I see when I go to the URL manually in Google Chrome, and then view the HTML.

This causes my application to get some job postings that are not on the webpage I am trying to scrape.

For instance, when I scrape https://se.indeed.com/jobb?q=Internship&l=Stockholm&start=0 my program finds the following company names:

```
[['Nordic Tech House',
  'Beaubi',
  'NO COMPANY NAME AVAILABLE',
  'National Pen',
  'SWEDISH STOCKINGS',
  'Above Agency',
  'BNP Paribas',
  'Flattered',
  'Stronger',
  'Doberman',
  'Tink',
  'Google',
  'BDO AB',
  'Amuseio AB',
  'Beaubi']]
```

However, when I actually visit the webpage, there is no job posting from Google, Amuseio etc., and furthermore some of the companies on the actual webpage are missing.

I have gone through the HTML-code which BeautifulSoup returns in the variable "soup" (see below) and compared it to the actual HTML-code on the webpages. In the HTML which is returned by BeatifulSoup, certainly Google and Amuseio are there. However, this is not the same HTML as I see when I inspect the page in the browser.

When I try to scrape https://se.indeed.com/jobb?q=Summer+Internship&l=Stockholm, everything works fine. This site does not have any pagination.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

source = requests.get('https://se.indeed.com/jobb?q=Internship&l=Stockholm&start=0') 
#THE URL WHICH PRODUCES THE STRANGE HTML

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

articles = soup.find_all('div', class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard') 
#All job postings seem to be in a div with the class mentioned above. 

def withdraw_company_names():
    lst_of_company_names = []
    for posting in articles:
        try:
            Company = posting.find('span', class_='company').text.strip()
        except:
            Company = "NO COMPANY NAME AVAILABLE"
        print("Name: ", Company)
        lst_of_company_names.append(Company) 

    return lst_of_company_names
```

Basically what I wonder:

Does anyone know why wrong HTML-code is returned in the first case?

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, you want to get all Jobs Post with there details and then filtered by the company.
You are in the right track, now you need to make other request, in this case for each post get the **data-jk** element, for example: data-jk="3a919d6b1b5070ca" and make a request to https://se.indeed.com/visajobb?jk=3a919d6b1b5070ca

You will get all the information from that post
Now, save the data as you prefer